# Catalog Search gives different results every request : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I did search several consecutive times for catalog search in the search box in the header of the store, but every time gave me different results as following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also, I can see this difference when use REST API :

> `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=life&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=relevance`

Can any body give an explanation ?

Comment: +1 For the question , lets wait for the good answer and yes its reproducible  for me . Its giving different result each time

Comment: No reply until now !!